# Conversion to Parallel/TPL for this Async code

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm wondering as to how I'd go aroung converting this Begin-End-Async approach to the newer TPL syntax:

```
    public override IAsyncResult BeginRegisterClaimant(ClaimantSex claimantSex, AgeGroup ageGroup, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        AsyncResult<string> asyncResult = new AsyncResult<string>(callback, state);
        InitManagementProxy();
        m_management.RegisterClaimantCompleted += RegisterClaimantCallbackInternal;
        m_management.RegisterClaimantAsync(m_configurationID, (PowWow.Service.ClaimantSex)claimantSex, (PowWow.Service.AgeGroup)ageGroup, new object[]
        { this, asyncResult
        });
        return asyncResult;
    }

    public override string EndRegisterClaimant(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        if (!(asyncResult is AsyncResult<string>))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid IAsyncResult object");
        }
        return ((AsyncResult<string>)asyncResult).Close();
    }

    private void InitManagementProxy()
    {
        WSHttpBinding binding;

        if (m_management != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        m_management = new PowWow.Service.VerifierContractClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(m_managementUri));
        m_management.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = m_userName;
        m_management.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = m_password;
    }

    private static void RegisterClaimantCallbackInternal(object senderObject, PowWow.Service.RegisterClaimantCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        PowWowVerifier powWowVerifier = (PowWowVerifier)((Object[])eventArgs.UserState)[0];

        powWowVerifier.m_management.RegisterClaimantCompleted -= RegisterClaimantCallbackInternal;
        powWowVerifier.m_management.Close();
        powWowVerifier.m_management = null;

        if (eventArgs.Error != null)
        {
            ((AsyncResult<string>)((Object[])eventArgs.UserState)[1]).OnException(eventArgs.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            ((AsyncResult<string>)((Object[])eventArgs.UserState)[1]).OnExecuted(eventArgs.Result);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
ATM, cancellation is not required. Progress reporting maybe required but not a priority.

Comment: Is this service side async or client side? Ah I see - all client side

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to wrap your existing code in a TaskCompletionSource and return it's Task - this will then fit in with the new async/await model coming in C# 5

Comment: I cannot do async/await as this code is in production. C# 5 is not on the company's upgrade list. And I'm writing a new verifier on the current one. i was hoping to do it the new TPL syntax way, based on Tasks rather then AsynResults etc.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use async/await - I was just stating that once you have the TPL pattern it will make it a natural fit for async/await when you migrate to C# 5 in the future. For existing code the easiest migration path to Tasks is to use TaskCompletionSource

Comment: Ah. understood. Will try now.

Comment: Using this article right now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx